# How to make this Code SonarClud Compliant

Tags: c#, sonarcloud, .net-8.0

I have a custom Exception:

```
namespace BO.Application.Shared.Errors;
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
[Serializable]
public class NullReferenceException : System.NullReferenceException
{
    private const string ErrorMessage = "VariableNotSet:{0}";
    public NullReferenceException()
    {
    }
    public NullReferenceException(string message, System.Exception innerException) : base(message, innerException)
    {
    }
    public NullReferenceException(string name) : base(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, ErrorMessage, name))
    {
    }
    protected NullReferenceException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
#pragma warning disable SYSLIB0051 // Type or member is obsolete
Do not suppress issues.
        : base(info, context)
#pragma warning restore SYSLIB0051 // Type or member is obsolete
    {
    }
}
```

I need the `protected NullReferenceException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)` constructor to have all needed construuctors for sonar to be happy

But if I add that then the Roslyn analyzer is not happy since I Use `.Net 8` and this is depricated

Witch in turn also shows up in sonar.

If I mark the constructor as depricated Sonar tels me to remove depricated code

IF I suppress the Roslyn message it Sonar tels me not to suppres issiues

Is there any way to make that compliant without disabling the rule in sonar?

Comment: Eeeeh, .NET 8 isn't deprecated at all, nor is *any* .net-version. You can of course use it. However as for all LTS-version support ends after 3 years. Anyway why do you even derive `NullReferenceException` in the first place? That seems pretty odd to me.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain OP is saying the constructor is obsolete https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullreferenceexception.-ctor?view=net-8.0#system-nullreferenceexception-ctor(system-runtime-serialization-serializationinfo-system-runtime-serialization-streamingcontext)

Comment: The constructor `protected NullReferenceException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)` is deprcated in `.Net  8`

Comment: Sounds like you should submit a bug to Sonar and disable this check while they fix it.